# "Fatal error: Uncaught UnhandledMatchError: Unhandled match value of type string"

Tags: php, switch-statement, php-8

Why I'm getting an error while executing a match expression:

```
$number = '1';

$result = match($number) {
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3, 4 => 'three or four',
};

echo $result;
```

> Fatal error:  Uncaught UnhandledMatchError: Unhandled match value of
> type string

Answer (score 6):

A [match expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php), as is stated in the documentation, must contain an exhaustive pattern.

The error `UnhandledMatchError` happens when there isn't any matching pattern. The second thing is that `match` is type sensitive, so it doesn't cast a value to the corresponding patterns. If you pass the string `'1'`, it doesn't cast to the int `1`. A possible solution would be providing a default value or cast the value to the correct type.

```
$result = match($number) {
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3, 4 => 'three or four',
    default => 'unknown',
};
```

or

```
$result = match((int)$number) {
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3, 4 => 'three or four',
};
```